# Player object's model starts to shake after some time

Tags: unity, rendering, models, 3d-modeling

I created a default scene in a new project and imported a model from Unity's asset store and then get this strange behavior of the model starting to shake for no reason after some time after starting the game.

I also have a script to read keyboard input and then apply forces to the model when the player presses some keys but the shaking of the model starts to happen even when the player does absolutely nothing.

I'm really confused and have no idea where to look for a problem and google doesn't seem to have a solution to this either.

[image]

Comment: We need way more details, if you disable the script with the keyboard, does the same thing happen? The model that you imported, does it have any scripts attached? If you disable them is the shaking still active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. I noticed the Y coordinate for the object was dropping when in game. I forgot to switch off "Use Gravity".

I'm creating a space-shooter game and didn't have any points of reference to see that my player object was falling. And once the Y coordinate reaches values below -10000 units the precision drops (not enough digits for the fraction) so the translation now cannot be shown smoothly and instead looks like the model is "shaking".

[image]